# Extract Words As A List After A Specicfic Word

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string

I've got this DataFrame, which is a description of sports and their leagues:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'text': ['The following leagues were identified: sport: basketball league: NBA sport: soccer league:EPL sport: football league: NFL']
})

df.text.iloc[0]
===============
The following leagues were identified: sport: basketball league: NBA sport: soccer league: EPL sport: football league: NFL
```

I need to extract all the sport names (which are coming after `sport:`) and put them as a list in a new column `sports`. I'm trying the following code:

```
pat = 'sport:\W+(?P<sports>(?:\w+))'
new = df.text.str.extract(pat, expand=True)
df.assign(**new)
===============
                        text                              sports
0   The following leagues were identified: sport: ...   basketball
```

However, it's returning only the 1st occurrence of the sport as a standalone string, whereas I need all the sports as a list.

**Desired output:**

```
               text                               sports
0   The following leagues were ...  [basketball, soccer, football]
```

What would be the smartest way of doing it? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Series.str.findall`:

```py
df['sports'] = df['text'].str.findall(r'sport:\W*(\w+)')
```

Pandas test:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'text': ['The following leagues were identified: sport: basketball league: NBA sport: soccer league:EPL sport: football league: NFL']
})
```

Output:

```
>>> df['text'].str.findall('sport:\W*(\w+)')
0    [basketball, soccer, football]
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Comment: Great. Thank you @wiktor-stribizew. Appreciate. I have one more question -- if I have a sentence `including basketball, soccer and football`. How can I extract this into `[basketball, soccer, football]`

Comment: @Roy Like `df = pd.DataFrame({
    'text': ['The following leagues were identified: sport: basketball league: NBA sport: soccer league:EPL sport: football league: NFL', "including basketball, soccer and football"]
})`?

Comment: Yes, exactly! That's another pattern.

Comment: @Roy And what are this pattern requirements?

Comment: Hi @wiktor-stribizew. I tried this script and it's working: 

```text1 = re.findall(r'including.*', text)

  text_final = ' '.join(text1).replace('including', '').replace('and', ',').replace('.', '').replace(' ', '').split(',')```

Comment: @Roy In Pandas, it can be done like `df['new_sports'] = df['text'].str.extract(r'including\s*(.+)', expand=False).str.replace(' and ', ',', regex=False).str.split(r'\s*,\s*')`